# Robolectric: simulate network error in test

Tags: unit-testing, networking, robolectric

How is it possible to produce the same exception like during a real connection-error in robolectric tests?

I want to how the program acts if the network is currently not available. Is there a possibility to produce the same exception for my HttpClient?

I already tried:

```
Robolectric.getFakeHttpLayer().interceptHttpRequests(false); // with real network to a non existent IP
```

and

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
```

and

```
Robolectric.addPendingHttpResponse(404, null);
```

but none of them produces the same reactions like a real connection-loosing.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked `Robolectric`'s `FakeHttpLayer` and haven't found way to simulate throwing an `IOException`.

So use mocking to make it working for you. First introduce `HttpClientFactory` (if you use `HttpClient`, you can use same approach for `HttpUrlConnection`):

```
public class HttpClientFactory {
    public HttpClient createClient() {
     return new DefaultHttpClient();
    }
}
```

And now in your networking layer use factory instead of constructors (let for simplicity assume that it is synchronous):

```
public class HttpTransportLayer {
    private final HttpClientFactory clientFactory;

    public HttpTransportLayer() {
        this(new HttpClientFactory());
    }

    // For tests only
    HttpTransportLayer(HttpClientFactory clientFactory) {
        this.clientFactory = clientFactory;
    }

    public String requestData(String url) {
        HttpClient client = factory.createClient();
        ...
    } 
}
```

So now you can in tests use `Mockito`:

```
HttpClient mockedClient = mock(HttpClient.class);

@Before
public void setUp() {
     HttpClientFactory factory = mock(HttpClientFactory.class);
     when(factory.createClient()).thenReturn(mockedClient);

     target = new HttpTransportLayer(factory);
}

@Test
public void whenIOExceptionThenReturnNull() {
    when(mockedClient.execute(any(HtptUriRequest.class))).thenThrow(new IOException());

    String data = target.requestData("http://google.com");

    assertThat(data).isNull();
}
```

That is dummy test and usually nobody will return null in case of error.

You could also task look to some dependency injection framework like `Dagger` to minimise injection code.

If you use any good framework for networking like `Retrofit` or `Volley` then it is even simpler - you don't need to mock anything and just invoke you error callback.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the hints. A combination between a Factory, Dagger and an an implementation of HttpClient helped me out :)