# Change Android connectivity with Robolectric

Tags: java, android, robolectric

I'm working on an Android project that gets unit tested with Robolectric.

I don't get the disabling of the internet connection to work.

I have a method that uses an HttpUrlConnection to send a request to and get a response from an HTTP server: `boolean sendRequest()`. And it returns true, if the request was successfull.

```
private boolean sendRequest() throws Exception
{
    URL url = new URL("http://example.com");
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection( );
    int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode( );
    return statusCode == 200;
}
```

In a helper class I have two methods: `void setConnectivity(boolean enable)` and `boolean checkConnectivity()`.

```
public static void setConnectivity( boolean enabled) throws Exception
{
    Context context = Robolectric.application.getApplicationContext();

    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    Robolectric.shadowOf(wifiManager).setWifiEnabled(enabled);
    wifiManager = (WifiManager) Robolectric.application.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    Robolectric.shadowOf(wifiManager).setWifiEnabled(enabled);

    ConnectivityManager dataManager  = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    Robolectric.shadowOf(dataManager).setBackgroundDataSetting(enabled);
    dataManager = (ConnectivityManager)Robolectric.application.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    Robolectric.shadowOf(dataManager).setBackgroundDataSetting(enabled);

    Robolectric.shadowOf(dataManager.getActiveNetworkInfo()).setConnectionStatus(enabled);

    Intent connIntent = new Intent(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    connIntent.putExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, enabled);
    Robolectric.getShadowApplication().sendBroadcast(connIntent);

    ShadowSettings shadowSettings = new ShadowSettings();
    shadowSettings.setWifiOn(enabled);
    shadowSettings.setAirplaneMode(enabled);
}

public static boolean checkConnectivity() throws Exception
{
    Context context = Robolectric.application.getApplicationContext();

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo wifiNetwork = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    if (wifiNetwork != null && wifiNetwork.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }

    NetworkInfo mobileNetwork = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    if (mobileNetwork != null && mobileNetwork.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I already packed everything I could find for disabling the internet connection via Robolectric into the `setConnectivity()` method, and when checking via `checkConnectivity()` I get the expected return value, BUT `sendRequest()` always returns true, although I'm expecting requests to fail when the internet connection is disabled.

```
@Test
public void testConnectivity() throws Exception
{
    setConnectivity(true);
    assertTrue(checkConnectivity());
    assertTrue(sendRequest());

    setConnectivity(false);
    assertFalse(checkConnectivity());
    assertFalse(sendRequest()); // Assertion failed
}
```

Am I missing a Robolectric method call for disabling the internet connection? Or maybe my whole approach is wrong and actual requests are never affected by Robolectric settings?

The test method is in a test class with the Robolectric test runner.

Comment: what does your method sendRequest() do ?

Comment: edited my question and added source code of the method (just wrote it - the original is different, but both have the same issue)

Comment: Why do you expect that send request fails? Usually you wrap network code with checking first that network is connected

Comment: 1) I expect that the request fails because I thought the internet connectivity gets disabled with `setConnectivity(false)`. I can't find any info if that's a wrong assumption or not. 2) For checking the internet connectivity I need a Context, but I'm developing an SDK and can't require the developer to supply one. That's why I have a method similar to the above sendRequest, where I expect an Exception if the request fails. This works on the device, but not with my unit tests. That's why I asked this question :)

Comment: @backendev Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30638439/950427

Answer (score 0):

As my question is not getting any answers and I can't find answers on the web, I guess it's just not possible.

I found a Stack Overflow answer that seems to solve what I want to achieve, although it's not with Robolectric, but with a mocking framework:
[Answer to "Robolectric: simulate network error in test"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20965885/3596676)